# gaussian filter correct implementation

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I am trying to implement Gaussian filter in Matlab, I have read some material and there are slightly differences :
one implemented like this:

```
f = fspecial ('gaussian', 3);
result = filter2(f,image);
```

other implemented like this:

```
f = fspecial('gaussian',3);
result = conv2(double(image),f);
```

That makes me confused. can anyone help me figure which is correct? thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They both are. From the documentation page for [`filter2`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/filter2.html) under Algorithms:

> Given a matrix X and a two-dimensional FIR filter h, filter2 rotates your filter matrix 180 degrees to create a convolution kernel. It then calls conv2, the two-dimensional convolution function, to implement the filtering operation.

So `filter2` rotates the kernel 180 degrees. Won't that produce a different result? Let's check the documentation for [`fspecial`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/fspecial.html) and see how it generates a gaussian kernel (emphasis mine):

> h = fspecial('gaussian', hsize, sigma) returns a **rotationally symmetric** Gaussian lowpass filter of size hsize with standard deviation sigma (positive). hsize can be a vector specifying the number of rows and columns in h, or it can be a scalar, in which case h is a square matrix. The default value for hsize is [3 3]; the default value for sigma is 0.5. Not recommended. Use imgaussfilt or imgaussfilt3 instead.

So the kernel produced by `fspecial` is rotationally symmetric, and rotating a symmetric kernel 180 degrees has no effect, so the two are identical.

If you create your own kernel that is *not* symmetric, then the two operations will yield different results.

Comment: I'd also like to point out that the main difference between `filter2` and `conv2` is that `filter2` performs correlation while `conv2` performs actual convolution.  `conv2` natively rotates the kernel by 180 degrees and so by `filter2` performing an additional 180 degree rotation prior to `conv2`, the kernel orientation remains the same and thus `filter2` performs correlation.

Comment: But if the case is image = [0 3 5 6] and kernel= [2 3]. So if I want to apply Gaussian to this case. which is correct way? I though rotating kernel in this case has effect to different result.

Comment: @computerluv Have a look at the edit and see if this addresses your concern.